# Throttle concurrent webservice calls on database operations

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency

I have Spring WS call where I perform some lookups and end up in a decision where either to update existing data or insert new row into the database. Problem is, when I would perform 2 same insert calls on that endpoint at the same time, then the `insertData()` method gets executed twice in different threads and 2nd call usually results in `SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` as first execution already inserted the record and 2nd tries to do the same with same version number.

How should I perform some kind of throttle strategy on the method calls so they would be performed in some sort of sequence or put in queue? I also have a specific field against which to check/cache the calls. Any suggestions?

Comment: A bit too general to get a good answer. But typically it is solved by locking, you can use DB locking, JPA locking (depending on your implementation) to prevent simultation modification of same objects. However, more worrying is that your insertData can get the same new Key twice, each insert should use a new key value unless the keys comes from outside word. And finally you could try to recover from the DuplicateKeyException and retrieve previously inserted object, it would be more efficient than locking provided that your insert collisions are not too often

Comment: My mistake, it's not DuplicateKey actually, it's custom constraint that gets violated, ID on insertion would come different of course, it's the version number of that record that must be unique, in that case it wants to insert it with the same version. DB operations are using jdbc template. I would avoid locking on database level as it's preferred that when the first insert comes in its some parameter is put into a list to check against next queries coming in, if same already exist then throw the 2nd away as it's idendical query anyway.

Comment: As I said do you really have so many collisions (it would normally happen only if your client/users invoke same comment simultanousely) if it is rare even it is easier and better to ignore(deal with) the Constraint exception on those few occasions. And if they are not rare than you should probably rethink your design.
Otherwise you have to sort concurrency properly, for example ConcurrentHashMap to keep currently processed ids with atomic checks, for example using putIfAbsent.

Comment: There aren't many and there's nothing we can actually do about that since the requests are made from other systems. It's more just to keep the error logs clean as these don't need to be there. I went with the Memorizer pattern by Brian Goetz where I would put the FutureTask-s in the map and use my parameter as a key to check for existing ones.

Comment: Two inserts happen nearly instantaneously right? The first one succeeds the second one fails due to a specific error. Trap that error and increment the version number rerun transaction and done.

Comment: Same inserts happen at the same moment, maybe milliseconds apart. It's not necessarily first that wins the race, could be the call that was later. I have no use of the 2nd one as the queries itself are exactly the same so I just would throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the database you are using, but most of the databases have "upsert" functionality in some way. Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and many others support it. An upsert operation **atomically** updates the data if it exists in the table, or inserts it if it does not exist in the table. By this way, you make your database handle the concurrency issue.

If you want to do it programatically, here is a sample approach:

I assume that you have some kind of a unique value that results a constraint violation when you want to insert it to the database multiple times. That unique value, or any other unique value can be used in this particular method.

```
    String uniqueKey = "someKey"; // This is your unique value that you get somehow

    ConcurrentMap<String, Object> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

    Object lock = locks.get(uniqueKey);

    if(lock == null) {
        Object previous = locks.putIfAbsent(uniqueKey, lock = new Object());
        if(previous != null) {
            lock = previous;
        }
    }

    synchronized (lock) {
        // you can safely check your database to do an update or an insert here. 

    }
```

If two threads try to make an operation on the same uniqueKey value, they will end up trying to enter to the synchronized block on the same lock object. Therefore, they will execute the synchronized block one by one. However, please be aware that this approach does not remove the lock objects from the concurrent map. It means that your memory consumption will increase with every new uniqueKey value and you may need to find a way to remove the unnecessary locks objects eventually.

Another method is using a number of queues for executing your operations on the database. For each queue, you have to make two a guarantee as following:

- The operation K + 1 must be executed after the operation K is completed.
- All of the operations for a specific uniqueKey value must be put into the same queue.